# What does カイデー mean?

Tags: translation

I saw this in a tweet just a few minutes ago.

アメリカ…俺よりカイデーな選手がゴロゴロ(ﾟoﾟ;;

This could be talking about the world cup.

I can't find カイデー defined anywhere. What does it mean? What does that tweet say?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not fully sure, but it may be an instance of playing around with words: cut a word in half and put them together in the wrong order, which is often done especially among celebrities. In this case:

> でかい → デ + カイ → カイ + デ → カイデー [Vowel lengthened to make it four-mora, which sounds more familiar and cool]

In this case, it will mean

> America ... There are bunches of players around who are larger than me.

Comment: A couple of years ago it was popular among the JK crowd to pronounce ごめん as メンゴー, so this is probably the same thing.

Comment: @Derek Yes. That is another example.

Comment: Or the famous まいう!

Answer (score 3):

I'm inclined to believe it's the reordering of pronunciation. English has a similar concept. It's called Pig Latin(which actually has nothing to do with Latin).

This answer might not be directly relevant to Japanese, but if the concept of reordering exists in English, it seems to make it more believable that similar phenomenon occurs in other languages.

> The first onset (the consonant (cluster) that comes before a vowel) is put to the back of the word, then "ay" is added to it.
>
> E.g. "Scram" turns into "Amscray" (Typical Pig Latin example. It was frequently used to the point where it eventually became a recognized English word)
>
> E.g. "Bird" turns into "Irdbay"

Comment: Reordering is indeed observed widely in other languages. It is called metathesis. `scram` and `bird` are mono-syllabic. So the first syllable is the whole word. I think you meant onset (i.e., the consonant (cluster) that comes before a vowel).

Comment: Ah yes that was what I intended to mean. But I didn't have the exact term for it. I'll fix it. Thanks.